# Is There A Way To Install Unstable Version of Plugin via Built-in Plugin Installer

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering if there is a way to install an unstable version of a published plugin.

Let's say I updated my plugin version 1.0 to 1.1.

Then I put `Stable tag: 1.0` in the `readme.txt` file so that everyone downloads the stable version v1.0.

Now my question is that if I want to test the unstable version on one of the remote servers, isn't it possible to install v1.1 with the built-in plugin installer?

I'm currently doing this way:

1. deactivate the old version
2. delete the plugin
3. upload the unstable version
4. activate it.

If the updating process could be shorten this way, it would really save my time.

1. search and find the plugin name to install in the `Add New` page.
2. click on the unstable version link.

Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the answer you are looking for but...

I was running into the same issue and instead what I have chosen to do is actually edit my plug-in on a "test-bed" site.  I have a site that I test all of my modifications on before publishing and I access the files directly via FileZilla FTP Client.

This allows me to take the most up to date file from the server, edit it on my machine (using Notepad++) and upload the change to the server for testing.  If it breaks the site in some way I can always re-upload the original via FTP and everything is back online.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So this seems to be a kind of issue held by many plugin developers. Thanks for sharing your way of testing plugins. I'll consider using FTP.